# How to prevent grid divs from expanding in height with its content?

Tags: html, css, gridview

so I have a simple grid with 4 divs. Divs 2,3 and 4 contain charts and div 1 is reserved for some text.
When adding more text to div 1 it automatically expands in height to accomodate the text. This also triggers the other divs to stretch in y and they "fall" out of the wrapper div. I tried adding overflow:auto; to div 1 but it just expands to accomodate the content.
I also tried with min-width = 0; and min-height = 0; in order to force the grid items not to expand but did not work.

Here is the code...

```
<div id="Progress" class="tabcontent">
                        <div class="progress-content">
                            <div class="progress-content-box first-box">
                                <div class="box-title">
                                    <h2>Summary</h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="summary">
                                    Progress summary will take data from "1", "2" and "3" cards and provide information in form of bar, pie, doughnut, polar charts!
                                </div>
                                <div class="box-content">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="progress-li">just some text</li>
                                        <li class="progress-li">just some text</li>
                                        <li class="progress-li">just some text</li>
                                        <li class="progress-li">just some text</li>
                                        <li class="progress-li">just some text</li>
                                        <li class="progress-li">just some text</li>
                                        <li class="progress-li">just some text</li>
                                        <li class="progress-li">just some text</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="progress-content-box second-box">
                                <div class="chart-container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                                    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="progress-content-box third-box">
                                <div class="chart-container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                                    <canvas id="myChart5"></canvas>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="progress-content-box fourth-box">
                                <div class="box-charts" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
                                    <canvas id="myChart1"></canvas>
                                </div>
                                <div class="box-charts" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
                                    <canvas id="myChart2"></canvas>
                                </div>
                                <div class="box-charts" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
                                    <canvas id="myChart3"></canvas>
                                </div>
                                <div class="box-charts" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
                                    <canvas id="myChart4"></canvas>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>



.tabcontent{
    display: none;
    border-top: none;
    grid-row: 3/21;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.progress-content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.progress-content-box {
    background: #eee;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px #708090;
    padding: 1rem;
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: 0;
}
.first-box {
    grid-column: 1/3;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    
}
.box-content {
    padding-left: 1rem;
    min-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box-content ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li{
    font-size: 14px;
}
li::before {
    content: "•"; 
    padding-right: 8px;
    color: #708090; 
}
.fourth-box {
    padding: 1rem;
    grid-column: 1/5;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 1rem;
}
```

*class tabcontent has dispay=none; and I am using js to change the display to grid when a tab is clicked...*
So the question would be, how do I preserve the height of the divs when the content is too large to accomodate and provide vertical scrollbar?

Thank you in advance,

Borko

Comment: if you want to give your divs a fixed height, then use the height: property and give it a value, for example: height: 200px;. Otherwise, they will expand by default. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp

Comment: Yes, i know, but i do not want to give them a fixed height in px...I would like to use % (if the screen is bigger they should expand in available size but keep the grid and ratio ) and again when the content is greater than the container I would like to  keep the height and add scroll... * Actually I tried with fixed size in px and it works, the thing is only I want them to resize with % when using it on laptop (1920 x 1080) or on monitor with bigger resolution...*

Comment: if you want to use a vertical height %, the parent element must have a fixed height. A % based height value of a parent without a fixed value will not calculate properly afaik.

Comment: Or I could use media queries? set fixed size in px, one for 1920 x 1080 and another for bigger screen sizes...? what would you suggest? Thanks for helping me!

Comment: my suggestion is to provide us with graphical examples of your desired result so we can have more context